SharePoint Online mapped network drive Access Denied
Good day All
My client's setup:
Got a Windows 11 PC (aka file server) setup with OneDrive Client to sync files to PC's local hard drive.
Those folders are then shared with local file share/drive mapping with everyone in the office having full access. The reason for this is, the client works with big drawings, and it is faster to save the files locally than to wait for OneDrive Client to sync files between team members.
My issue:
When I save a file via the mapped network drive everything works fine as follows:
Save file via Mapped Drive -> All local users can access the file -> OneDrive Client sync file to SharePoint Online -> All users working from home can access file via SharePoint Online.
But when a home user saves a file via SharePoint the following happens:
User working from home save file in SharePoint -> OneDrive Client sync file to local hard drive -> File is accessible on the PC (aka file server) -> Access Denied error when opening the file via Mapped Drive.
To me it looks like the new file saved via SharePoint Online does not inherit the parent file permissions from the file share.
"Everyone" has full rights on the file share.
When I go on the PC (aka file Server) to the file share security and select "Replace all child object permissions entries with inheritable permission entries from this object" and apply, I can then open the file via the Mapped Drive, but any files after that added by a home user via SharePoint Online, we get Access Denied again for that new file.
Anyone tried a setup like this or experience an issue like this?
